# Automatic variable in C not initialized but given fixed value within loop

Tags: c, dev-c++

I read that automatic variables in C, if not initialized to values, contain garbage values. However, I found something that did not correspond to my understanding. Consider the following piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0 ; i< 10; i++)
    {   
        int x;
        int a = 500;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", a, x);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
500     2
500     2
500     2
500     2
500     2
500     2
500     2
500     2
500     2
500     2
```

My question is - shouldn't I be expecting garbage values instead of 2s? I ran the program on Dev-C++ on a Windows machine.

Comment: Isn't `2` a garbage value? Did you expect something like this? `&^^%U^%&^`

Comment: I expected a different value each time

Comment: Try printing out the address of `x`. As long as the address is not changed u might not see a difference in the garbage value.

Comment: The address remains the same, but I was unaware that the value of x inside the loop. 
When I initialize 'x' outside, and print it outside, I get gibberish, but when I print the same 'x' inside the for loop , I get the the 2s. 
So , in the same program, 'x' has one garbage value outside, another garbage value (which remains constant) inside. This is what I am not able to comprehend.

Comment: @RahulRajaram  where is you other x?

Comment: The 'x' was initialized outside the loop and printed once outside. Sorry, I reached an erroneous conclusion that it happens every time. However, the first time I tried it, it did happen. Now I get 2, even when I print it outside.

Comment: "I expected a different value each time " -- you shouldn't have. "This is what I am not able to comprehend." -- How odd. Since the behavior is undefined, the pattern of behavior is also undefined and may differ from case to case.

Answer (score 3):

`Uninitialized` means declared but is not set to a definite known value before it is used.

It will have SOME value, but not a predictable one.In your case it is `2`. On other system it may be anything else.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer I could make use of.

Comment: @RahulRajaram This is called undefined behavior :) also as a side note -- don't use `main( )` always use `int main(void)`

Comment: I guess I have a wider, more accurate view about 'undefined behaviour' now.

Comment: The value could in fact be different every time ... that's within the scope of "undefined behavior".

Comment: Should also add that "garbage" is kind of a misnomer--it implies that the value will be junk (which is what the OP expected).  Garbage really means that it can't be relied on for any useful function, not that the compiler can't output a clean-looking number.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is 2 each iteration of the loop is because you are using the same stack location every time.  For each iteration:

1. An int is created on the top of the stack -- its value is uninitialized -- 2 in your case
2. Another int is created and initialized to 500.
3. printf() is called
4. The 2 ints created are removed from the stack
5. Repeat above steps until i == 10

Answer (score 1):

After read you comment , I think you mean you code like this:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   main()
   {
       int i = 0;
       int x = 1;
       printf("%d\n", x);
      for (i = 0 ; i< 10; i++)
       {
          int x;
          int a = 500;
          printf("%d\t%d\n", a, x);

      }
  }
```

Print Screen:

```
1
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
500     -1216424736
```

While , the meaningful code is:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   main()
   {
       int i = 0;
       int x = 1;
       printf("%d\n", x);
       for (i = 0 ; i< 10; i++)
       {
          //int x;
          int a = 500;
          printf("%d\t%d\n", a, x);

      }
  }
```

Screen Print:

```
1
500     1
500     1
500     1
500     1
500     1
500     1
500     1
500     1
500     1
500     1
```

In the first code, I create a new x in  the loop ,the new x's survive range is only the loop,since I din't initialized it , it value is unknow. (once it is 0 another time it is -121642736 and your is 2).

The second code , The x in the loop is exactly the one out the loop , it is 1.

Comment: Actually, I declared 'x' only once and that was outside the loop.

Comment: @RahulRajaram Well, the code you post is not, and if you declared x in outside of the loop, did you initialize it?

Comment: Yes, I told you that it is not in the code I posted. I did not initialize it. I simply declared it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq  ok , I will modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to **initialize** your x variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0 ; i< 10; i++)
    {   
        int x = 0;//change this to whatever you want. The most common initial value is 0
        int a = 500;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", a, x);//this should print: "500    0" correctly, now
    }
}
```

What you're seeing is information from previous programs - aka **garbage data.**

Comment: I deliberately left 'x' uninitialized and expected a different value for x each time I printed it.

Comment: @RahulRajaram, Not necessarily. The OS could simply be loading the program to a section of memory that was available and not in use. Since your program is small, and doesn't involve a lot of memory globbing, that behavior is not unexpected.

Comment: What can also happen is that while you continue to use the memory, or background programs continue to run, _eventually_ you will get different data. What you should do is compare the memory addresses that the variable is accessing. Make note of it, and track it over the course of multiple runs (if you keep getting the same data). You'll notice that generally, your program will be occupying similar if not the same memory addresses as the uninitialized data remains more or less the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you please refer to my comment to the first reply to this question? I am not able to clear all my confusion.

Comment: I think your latest comment is helping a lot.

Comment: @RahulRajaram, I am glad to hear that. What you should note is that depending on the OS you're running, as well as the kernel, the way how memory is managed and brokered to programs plays a big part in the type of garbage you will see in a case like this.

Comment: "eventually you will get different data" -- one would not expect that during the duration of a loop (although it's *possible* because anything is possible for behavior that is undefined).

Comment: @JimBalter, Yes, eventually you will get different data from different iterations of the same program. I didn't mean different data __within__ the same loop run. Not at all. My apologies for misunderstanding previously conveyed.

Comment: You won't even get different results because of other programs unless you're running on an embedded device, because modern OSs zero all pages for security purposes. That 2 was stored on the stack by some piece of the OP's program. (There's startup code that runs before main runs.)

Answer (score 0):

`int x` defines storage (in MS Windows `int`s are 4 bytes).  That storage, like any other storage contains data, in your case it just happened to be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving `x` uninitialized will give it *some* value from a previous program or stack frame. In C, the memory blocks within a stack frame are not necessarily zero-filled like some languages have it, they remain in their previous (or old) state. This is more commonly known as a **garbage value**.

It's just a coincidence it is 2, it could have of easily been 1000 or 1293. The likely hood is you were very lucky and your variable `x` was assigned to the same block of memory for each execution of your program.

Comment: I disagree that `x` has “some” value. Accessing `x` is undefined behavior and the “value” you are talking about may be the number that, multiplied by 2, results in 1: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined